# Wordpress Active Plugins

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have in my website right now around 100 active plugins. I need to know a way to erase those active plugins that I'm not using. Actually that is affecting the speed of my website and back-end too.
In my side I found that does not exist a plugin that can tell me this...

Any suggestion, any advice will be really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/ to see what plugins are slowing you down.

The only way to know which plugins you are not using would be to check if/where they are used and for what.

You COULD deactivate one by one and make sure nothing breaks on the site.

There is otherwise no other way of knowing which you are or are not using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. I checked that Plugin before and yes! the plugin is really good!. But deactivate 100 plugins and see Which one is affecting the speed of my website is a huge work. I'm completely sure that I have around 30 that I'm not using. I think that this is a Wordpress issue. The way that they are handling the plugins are not good. They only allow Active, Inactive and Delete but these options can be better I mean allow the developers to see What's going on with the plugins without install 10  more plugins. This is an option that everybody use so in my opinion could be better.

Comment: I agree. However, it would be extremely difficult to find which plugin is being used and at what point. The P3 profiler should be able to tell you which plugin is causing your site to perform slow.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Steve!